# Nodejs Serialport not open after 1012 writes

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I'm using nodejs "v0.10.28" and npm "1.4.9", downloaded from http://nodejs.org.

I've installed serialport through npm

```
npm install serialport
```

My program is running on a Raspberry-pi and needs to keep sending updated values quickly through serialport, so I've created this test program.

```
var serialPort = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {
      baudrate: 9600
}, false);

console.log("Starting up serial host...");

var message = "Num: ";
var counter = 1000000;
function write()
{
        message= counter.toString();
        counter+=1;
        sp.open(function(err)
        {
                console.log("Writing serial data: " + message);
                sp.write(message, function(err, res)
                {
                        if (err)
                        {
                                console.log(err);
                        }
                        sp.close();
                });
        });
}

setTimeout(write, 10); //wait 10 ms for everything to initialize correctly
setInterval(write, 50); //write data every 50 ms
```

The program runs ok for exactly 1012 writes, then crashes.

Program output towards the end:

```
...
Writing serial data: 1001011
Writing serial data: 1001012
Writing serial data: 1001013
[Error: Serialport not open.]

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Serialport not open.
    at SerialPortFactory.SerialPort.close (/home/pi/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:476:17)
    at /home/pi/serialTest.js:25:7
    at SerialPortFactory.SerialPort.write (/home/pi/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:290:9)
    at /home/pi/serialTest.js:19:13
    at /home/pi/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:224:11
```

Why is it crashing?
Is there any buffer overflow in memory somewhere?
And why exactly 1012 writes? Very close to 1024, is it a coincidence?

Comment: What is on the other end of the serial port? It is equally likely that the receiving device is having a problem with the volume of data being sent, and is closing/crashing after 1012 messages have been sent.

Comment: @knolleary, the other end is a BASIC Stamp microcontroller, the only pin connected from the Raspberry-pi is the TX, there is no flow control. And no, the other end has no problems.

Comment: what's the `err` message say when you try to to open in `sp.open(function(err)` after 1012 iteration?

Comment: @hassansin [Error: Serialport not open.], the whole error output is up there in the post.

Answer (score 1):

A friend just helped with answering this privately so I'll share findings here.

Code:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {
      baudrate: 9600
}, false);

console.log("Starting up serial host...");

var message = "Num: ";
var counter = 1000000;

sp.open(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Port open error: ", err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Port opened!");
    }
});

function write()
{

        if (sp.isOpen())  {
            message= counter.toString();
            counter+=1;

            console.log("Writing serial data: " + message);
            sp.write(message, function(err, res)
            {
                    if (err)
                    {
                            console.log(err);
                    }
                    setTimeout(write, 50);
            });
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(write, 50);
        }
}

setTimeout(write, 10); //wait 10 ms for everything to initialize correctly
```

If you look closely you'll notice that now sp.open() is used once and in the beginning of write function sp.isOpen() is used to check if port is open.
Also setInterval(write, 50); is gone and now only use setTimeout(write, 10);

Code now works, but that still doesn't answer the question why did it use to crash when opening and closing the port in the previous code.